# Django query objects using non related models

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have these 3 models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name
  age

class Person_Address(models.Model):
  address
  number
  city
  state
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class State_Schedules(models.Model):
  state
  hour
```

I also have a `models.QuerySet` for the `State_Schedules` for filtering based on current time (basically the `contactables()` below).

How can I get the `Person` objects comparing it's `state` in django?

I tried this but it seems cumbersome having to fetch the `Persons` using their `Person_Address`.

```
persons = Person_Address.objects.select_related('person').filter(
  state__in=(
    _.state for _ in State_Schedules.objects.contactables()
  )
)
```

If I could access the `Person_Address` association as a keyword to the `Person`'s filter, this should be pretty easy, but I haven't found how to do so.

Is there a better approach or I'd have to resort to `raw` sql?

Comment: Note that in Django you normally use CamelCase without the underscore for model names, i.e. `PersonAddress` and `StateSchedule` (without the s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a foreign key from `Person_Address` to `Person`, so you can filter on the reverse relationship. Use double underscore notation to filter on fields in the `Person_Address` model.

```
states = [_.state for _ in State_Schedules.objects.contactables()]
people = Person.objects.filter(person_address__state__in=states)
```

Comment: I was soooo close! Thank you, mate!